# Unreal Engine 5.1 custom docker images creation failure

Tags: unreal-engine5

I am trying to build images for dev and runtime docker containers based on custom unreal engine (right now engine is a full copy of original 5.1 ue)
I am using information from official documentation from this page
https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Containers/HowTo/BuildingTheLinuxContainerImagesFromSource/

Steps to rep:
1)Clone unreal engine repo (git clone -b release --single-branch git@github.com:EpicGames/UnrealEngine.git)
2)Run Setup.sh
3)Run GenerateProjectFiles.sh
4)run ./build branchname repourl

Expected result:
Images builded successfully

Actual result:
Engine building fails with unknown error (full log with detailed information here
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kkGCqApdnQBLGYLy7yeHydwb-rTByEX3?usp=share_link)

Extra information:
I have the same error , when try to build 5.1 from epic games repo , but building 5.0 version is okay , after 4 hours of waiting process completed and all images are created(log with it also can be found by the link
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kkGCqApdnQBLGYLy7yeHydwb-rTByEX3?usp=share_link)

Part of the log with the warning after which engine building process stops:

```
#22 14630.5 LogCore: Warning: dlopen failed: libxkbcommon.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
#22 14630.5 LogShaderCompilers: Display: ================================================
#22 14630.5 LogShaderCompilers: Display: === FShaderJobCache stats ===
#22 14630.5 LogShaderCompilers: Display: Total job queries 0, among them cache hits 0 (0.00%)
#22 14630.5 LogShaderCompilers: Display: Tracking 0 distinct input hashes that result in 0 distinct outputs (0.00%)
#22 14630.5 LogShaderCompilers: Display: RAM used: 0.00 MB (0.00 GB) of 1587.20 MB (1.55 GB) budget. Usage: 0.00%
#22 14630.5 LogShaderCompilers: Display: === Shader Compilation stats ===
#22 14630.5 LogShaderCompilers: Display: Shaders Compiled: 0
#22 14630.5 LogShaderCompilers: Display: Jobs assigned 0, completed 0 (0.00%)
#22 14630.6 LogShaderCompilers: Display: Time at least one job was in flight (either pending or executed): 0.00 s
#22 14630.6 LogShaderCompilers: Display: ================================================
#22 14630.6 LogShaderCompilers: Display: Shaders left to compile 0
#22 14630.6 LogDerivedDataCache: Display: 
../../../Engine/DerivedDataCache/Compressed.ddp.14B7DC4256834265883 
9EAC5FDCACDCA: Opened pak cache for reading. (0 MiB)
#22 14630.6 LogDerivedDataCache: Display: ../../../Engine/DerivedDataCache/Compressed.ddp: Opened pak cache for writing.
#22 14630.6 LogDerivedDataCache: Display: Sucessfully wrote ../../../Engine/DerivedDataCache/Compressed.ddp.
#22 14630.6 libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: COULDN'T load dxcompiler.
#22 14630.6 Signal 6 caught
```

Comment: It would be best to include at least part of the logs here on Stack Overflow. Links may change or become invalid.